# Ignore the XMLNS prefixes in CSS

Tags: css, xml, css-selectors, xhtml, xml-namespaces

i use the CSS selector `xmlns\:div` for XMLNS to style my elements, but i cant use the tag elment selectors... for example `div{color:#fff;}`

NB: the XMLNS prefixes is generated automatically so i can't predict the string and use it like so `prefix1\:div{color:#fff;}`

xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns:aa='zz' xmlns:ee='rr'>
<head>
   <title></title>
   <style type="text/css">
      /* it work */ aa\:span{background: #00ff00;}
      /* it doesnt work */ span{background: #00ff00;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
       <aa:span id="span1">
          <aa:p>aaa</aa:p>
       </aa:span>
    </div>  
    <div>
       <ee:span id="span1">
          <ee:p>aaa</ee:p>
       </ee:span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need to see your XML.

Comment: I just published it...

Comment: Do you only want to select the elements for one namespace and not the other, or do you want to select any element with the same tag name?

Comment: any element with the same tag name, just like the normal HTML file...

Comment: I just realized that you said `\:` works. In that case you're not actually styling XML, you're styling HTML that looks like XML. In that case you have a major problem on your hands: you must serve the page as `application/xhtml+xml` if you haven't already, before you're able to work with the XML namespaces as they're intended for.

Comment: i'v insert a meta tag with content application/xhtml+xml but it steel doesnt work... is that what you mean by (serve the page as application/xhtml+xml)?

Comment: No, you need to ask the server to send a `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` header for your page.

Comment: Although BoltClock is correct, I note that in your sample, the html namespace is not declared, so switching to `application/xhtml+xml` will probably break the page entirely. You will need to add an attribute to the html element `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

Comment: Another reason the page is broken is because of the duplicate IDs. IDs must be unique within the document (not within the namespace).

Comment: @Mr Lister you just broke the work down :) so how can i separate the HTML tags if they have the same IDs, i work in a project which combine different HTML fragment sent from multiple users, it may be possible that some fragments contain's the same IDs... any help please... or should i post a new question?

Comment: @kapsula Sorry, but if you insert HTML from users into your document without any kind of sanitation, you've got bigger problems than just some IDs being the same.

Comment: @Mr Lister actually i'v added a prefixes with regexp preg_match_all in PHP to any attribute (IDs/css classes...) and i do so for the (less) files, and also for the (js) files... the system work fine and i have no problem. but i want to do it in efficient way, i dont now how ex: DRUPAL or JOOMLA manage the thing?

Comment: i think using XMLNS for HTML tags and tagert them in (js) with getElementsByNameNS and use the CSS selector xmlns\:div for CSS documents... but in this case i cant use the tag elment selectors in CSS documents... that's why i'v wrote this post...

Comment: @kapsula - Have you changed to using `application/xhtml+xml` yet? If not then you currently have a mix of HTML and XHTML technologies that going to be a world of pain. You can go wholly HTML or wholly XHTML, but don't try to mix them.

Comment: @Alohci not yet but i well in this evening, and i go back to you if I have a problem :), thanks Alohci...

Comment: @Alohci it worck's now :) it works now :) thank you Alohci, just i don't know why in internet explorer (8/7/6/5.5) tell's me if i want to download the file?, all other browsers they render the file... i'v added the line `<?php header('Content-type: application/xhtml+xml'); ?>` like you said...

Comment: IE9 is the first IE that supports XHTML files. Earlier IEs don't know what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

it's kinda weird because in the html render (browser) there's no more prefixes.
But, can you use a nasty trick like instead to build css on tag, you can build with ID.

Like :

```
// ninja coding =D
#span1{
  color : black;
  visible : hidden;
}
```

Maybe something interessant four you [here](http://www.lenzconsulting.com/namespaces-in-xslt/#xslt_1_0__creating_dynamic_namespace_nodes)